# Output when using FIRST and LAST

Tags: sas

Say we have the SAS code:

```
data t1 (keep=KEY COUNT C_AMT2 C_AMT);  
SET t1;
BY key;
RETAIN COUNT C_AMT;

IF FIRST.KEY THEN
    DO;
        COUNT=0;
        C_AMT2=0;
    END;

COUNT+1;
C_AMT=SUM(C_AMT2, C_AMT);

IF LAST.KEY THEN
OUTPUT;

RUN;
```

What would change here if I were to remove "IF LAST.KEY THEN OUTPUT;". The [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/63323/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1lltvbis7ye1an1eryo4leh2mck.htm) says that output causes SAS to write to the datastep immediately, not at the end of the data step. Because here it is right before the end of the data step, would this mean removing it would cause no difference?

Comment: The fact that C_AMT2 is set to 0 in the first.KEY statement is a bit weird, I would expect it to be C_AMT, if this is a running total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commas are an error here:

```
(keep=KEY, COUNT, C_AMT2, C_AMT)
```

Anyway:

```
RUN;
```

usually means:

```
output;
return;
```

But if SAS encounters an `output` statement in your code, the `output` at the end (enclosed in the run statement) will be ignored.

Hence, since your `output` statement is conditionally executed only `IF LAST.KEY`, in your dataset you will have only observations marked as last.key, because your `RUN;` will only mean `return`.

Something like:

```
data want; set have; output; run;
```

Is exactly the same to not explicit output:

```
data want; set have; output; run;
```

You can use output as you want:

```
data want01 want02;
set have;
if a then output want01;
if b then output want02;
run;

data want01;
var=var1;
output;
var=var2;
output;
run;
```

Comment: I see. So as it is, it is summing the c_amt variable over each key variable, and then writing to the dataset one time for each key. If I were to remove IF LAST.KEY, what would be happening then? @stat

Comment: If output is not conditionally executed with last.key, one observation for each iteration will be output in the final dataset.
data want; set have; somecode; output; run; 
is exactly the same to not expliciting output.

Comment: @Danzo, why not remove it and run it? Or generate sample data and test it?

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Reeza , testing is the best way to understand what SAS is doing.

Answer (score 3):

Removing it would cause a difference.

Then you would have a record for every value of key, assuming multiple values. Controlling the output means you'd have only the last record.

It looks like it's calculating a count and total so there are other ways to achieve this. I'm going to assume that there's some other code that you've suppressed.

The relevant section from the documentation that refers to this is in the link you have above

> **Implicit versus Explicit Output**
>
> By default, every DATA step contains an implicit OUTPUT statement at the end of each iteration that tells SAS to write observations to the data set or data sets that are being created. **Placing an explicit OUTPUT statement in a DATA step overrides the automatic output, and SAS adds an observation to a data set only when an explicit OUTPUT statement is executed.** Once you use an OUTPUT statement to write an observation to any one data set, however, there is no implicit OUTPUT statement at the end of the DATA step. In this situation, a DATA step writes an observation to a data set only when an explicit OUTPUT executes. You can use the OUTPUT statement alone or as part of an IF-THEN or SELECT statement or in DO-loop processing.

Here's some code that simulates your issue:

```
*Generate random data;
Data have;
do Key=1 to 2;
    do i=1 to 3;
        Amount=floor(rand('normal', 50, 5));
        OUTPUT;
    end;
end;

run;

data t1;
set have;
retain count C_Amt;
by Key;

if first.key then do;
count=0;
C_Amt=0;
end;

Count+1;
c_amt=sum(c_amt, amount);

if last.key then output;
run;

proc print data=t1;
run;

data t1;
set have;
retain count C_Amt;
by Key;

if first.key then do;
count=0;
C_Amt=0;
end;

Count+1;
c_amt=sum(c_amt, amount);

*if last.key then output;
run;

proc print data=t1;
run;
```

And the corresponding output:

With last.key then output

```
                      Obs    Key    i    Amount    count    C_Amt

                       1      1     3      46        3       147
                       2      2     3      44        3       154
```

And with out last.key
                          Obs    Key    i    Amount    count    C_Amt

```
                       1      1     1      47        1        47
                       2      1     2      54        2       101
                       3      1     3      46        3       147
                       4      2     1      61        1        61
                       5      2     2      49        2       110
                       6      2     3      44        3       154
```